# Tableau server error after upgrade

Tags: amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I have upgraded tableau server to 10.3.
after the upgrade, a specific dashboard with live connection to redshift began returning this error:

'ERROR: Fetch size 2048 exceeds the limit of 1000 for a single node configuration. Reduce the client fetch/cache size or upgrade to a multi node installation.;
Error while executing the query'

This dashboard works perfect on tableau server 10.2.
the redshift query returns a very small data set (<10 rows, 7 columns).

currently i have rolled back the upgrade.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: Try to fresh installation. uninstall previews version and install new one don't update. There might have some problem.

Comment: What OS are you using? Mac OS X?

Comment: Aws ec2 with Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when upgrading tableau server, there might be some issues with driver versions of data sources connectors.
What resolved that issue was installation of updated version of Redshift driver on the tableau server.

Had similar issue with MySQL... again, resolved by updating MySQL driver version.